How to hide Python class method outside the class (and I don't mean "double underscore" protected)
I'm trying to hide a class method if the class is used from outside. I have a
function A that does something and function B that uses A to do something else. E.g.:
class Some_Class:
   def funcA():
      do something

   def funcB():
      use funcA() to do this

I want funcA() to be not visible. If I make funcA protected: def __funcA():, fine, it can't
be accessed from outside, but then funcB() does not execute because it needs funcA().
Further, funcA() can still be seen from the outside, even if it's protected the outside can still
see that "it's there". Is there a way to hide it? so that to the outside doesn't know about it?
Why I want this is just that funcA() is unnecessary information to the outside.
What I can do is just bring funcA() outside the class, but is there a way to do it and keep it in
the class?
Follow up: I tried also to make it private with "single underscore" def _funcA(): but that doesn't even seem to do anything.

Your thinking is simply off here. "I tried also to make it private with "single underscore" def _funcA(): but that doesn't even seem to do anything." Yes, it absolutely does - it tells everyone that it's a private method. Python runs on the principle of "we're all adults here" so we all agree that we are going against the intent of the developer if we start playing with them. If you go further down a rabbit hole of forcing private methods, your code will become a mess

Even with the explanation why you want this, this seems like an XY problem. If the function does something relevant then it's necessary, and hiding it just makes for extra  busywork.

If you rename funcA, you do it everywhere, where it's defined and used

Having said that, writing the function in C or Rust would create some inconvenient barriers for casual readers of your code.

@triplee: Yes it's necessary but it's just the class contains a lot of attributes and methods so I want to minimize the information to the outside (and of course it shortens the code a bit). I just don't want people to see it and think "hey, what's funcA for?"

@TheMercury79 they may well want to ask "hey, what's funcA for?" just like they would in any other library. Just because you can list stuff as "private" in other languages doesn't physically prevent them seeing that. However, _funcA is simply the only standard you need to say "this is not part of the API. Don't touch it". Of course they can, but that's on them not you. It's literally the only sensible way to make things "private" in Python

This still begs the question, to what end? Regular users will usually not inspect the source at all and hiding stuff from those who look at it seems more malicious than helpful. Encapsulating messy stuff in a private function already conveys "you are not expected to understand this" and you can add a comment or docstring to emphasize that if you like. (Though it would arguably be better to actually document what it does and why; perhaps that way you can also relieve the pressure to hide it.)

thanks to all nice inputs here, I don't disagree with them. My question was mainly for learning purposes, which has been achieved.

How about this:
import functools


def expose_as(another_func_name: str):
    def be_private(func):
        @functools.wraps(func)
        def runner(*args, **kw):
            if not kw.pop('_force', None):
                raise RuntimeError(f'{func.__name__} is a private function, use {another_func_name} instead!')
            return func(*args, **kw)
        return runner
    return be_private


class MyClass:
    @expose_as('func_b')
    def func_a(self):
        print(111)

    def func_b(self):
        return self.func_a(_force=1)


print(MyClass().func_b())  # 111
print(MyClass().func_a())  # raises RuntimeError


This doesn't hide the implementation (whatever the OP actually means by that), just prevents its use.
